# Woocommerce Product Creation Automation - GAS - apps script

Tags: api, rest, woocommerce

running into problems between GAS and WC RESTv2, Im trying to create a simple product with custom attributes, while I am able to do so without any specific parameter the REST api return this error:

ERROR:

{"code":"rest_invalid_param","message":"Invalid parameter(s): attributes","data":{"status":400,"params":{"attributes":"attributes[0] is not of type object."},"details":{"attributes":{"code":"rest_invalid_type","message":"attributes[0] is not of type object.","data":{"param":"attributes[0]"}}}}}

````
// the product gets CREATED fine using this simple var data structure :
var data = 
        {
        "name" : " TESTING HERE TOO",
        //"sku" : "TESTINGINGING    ",
        "type" : "simple",
        "regular_price" : "1.99",
        "weight" : 10,
        "manage_stock" : true,
        "stock_quantity" : 10,
        "description" : "testing \n"  } ;
var surl = website + "/wp-json/wc/v2/products?consumer_key=" + keys + "&consumer_secret=" + scret;
var options = 
      {
        "method": "POST",
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8",
        "muteHttpExceptions": true,
        "payload": data
      };

``` // -- the product DOES NOT get created using this :
var data = 
        {
        "name" : " TESTING HERE TOO",
        //"sku" : "TESTINGINGING    ",
        "type" : "simple",
        "regular_price" : "1.99",
        "weight" : 10,
        "manage_stock" : true,
        "stock_quantity" : 10,
        "description" : "testing \n"  } ;
"attributes" : [ { "variation" : "false", "options" : "[ANY]", "id" : 0.0, "name" : "Supplier", "position" : 0.0, "visible" :"false"} , { "variation" : "false", "options" : "[ANY]", "id" : 0.0, "name" : "Invoice", "position" :1.0, "visible" :"false"}]
````

Any body could shed some light where could be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anybody stumble here, here´s the solution:

if you´d like to know where´s the bug, here it is

var options =
{
"method": "POST",
//"Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8", -- it does NOT WORK like content type must be JSON
"contentType": "application/json",
"muteHttpExceptions": true,
"payload": JSON.stringify(data2) -- as long as JSON payload thus stringify accord.
//"payload": data2
};

when you have a JSON within an array in GAS, the only way REST api calls will understand is if you modify 2 things

1. "contentType": "application/json",
   send the payload to rest api WC as json
2. "payload": JSON.stringify(data2)
   trans for the javascript object into json so WC rest api can understand

done.